# htaccess redirect working to mobile, but not to desktop

Tags: .htaccess

Mobile devices redirect to domain/m/request_uri, but if you put that URL in desktop, it should redirect to domain/request_uri.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(fb/)?(takeaction|\d{1,3})/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/m/(takeaction|\d{1,3})/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/m/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: What's wrong? Are you getting an error? What is the result you are expecting with a certain URL and what are you getting instead?

Comment: It's just not redirecting at all. I've managed to get this to redirect to root, so the RewriteCond line seems to work, but I think my problem is with RewriteRule not changing "domain.com/m/request" to "domain.com/request"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's just not redirecting at all. I've managed to get this to redirect to root, so the RewriteCond line seems to work, but I think my problem is with RewriteRule not changing "domain.com/m/request" to "domain.com/request"

Try removing the leading slash in your rewrite rule from:

```
RewriteRule ^/m/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

Leading slashes are removed from the URI when used to match against the `RewriteRule` directive when they are used in an htaccess file.